# Need Help with the definition of product of two ideals

Tags: ring-theory, soft-question, ideals

I know this are not ideals but for the purpose of being clear imagine $I=\{1,2,3\}$ $J=\{4,5,6\}$ where I and J are ideals

$IJ = \{ a_1b_1 + a_2b_2 + ...+a_nb_n \mid a_i\in I b_i\in J \space i=1,2...,n \space \land \space n\in \mathbb{N}^*\}$

Then $IJ= \{1*4,1*4+2*5,1*4+2*5+3*6\} =\{4,14,32\}$

Would this be right or Am I missing something about the definition?

Comment: Recall that tuple notation denotes an *ideal sum* $\,(a,b):= aR + bR.\,$
$\!\begin{align}{\rm Therefore}\qquad (a,b)(c,d) &= (ac,ad,bc,bd)\\
 {\rm by}\,\ (aR+bR)(cR+dR) &= acR+adR+bcR+bdR \end{align}\ \ $

Comment: Generally the product ot two ideals is defined to be the ideal generated by the products of elements from each ideal, i.e. the intersection of all ideals containing such products (i.e.  the smallest such ideal).

Answer (score 3):

In the definition of the product of two ideals, we're not saying take the first element of one ideal and multiply it by the first element of the next ideal, and so on. What the definition is saying is that you need to allow for arbitrary sums of any product of an element of $I$ with an element of $J$. Maybe a definition you would be more comfortable with is to define $IJ$ to be the ideal generated by the set $\{ab:a\in I\, b\in J\}$.

As an example, let's show that the ideal of even integers $I$, and the ideal of integers divisible by $3$ which we'll call $J$, has as its product the ideal of all integers divisible by $6$ which we'll call $K$.

Every multiple of $6$ can be written as $6z$ for some integer $z$, which is the same as $2\cdot 3\cdot z$ so that $6z$ is a multiple of $2$ times a multiple of $3$. Thus every multiple of $6$ is an element of $IJ$, so that $K\subseteq IJ$.

Conversely, every element of $IJ$ has the form $\sum_{i=1}^{n}a_ib_i$ where $a_i$ is in $I$ and $b_i \in J$.
But then every summand is divisible by $6$, so that the sum is divisible by $6$. This means that every element of $IJ$ is a multiple of $6$ so that $IJ\subseteq K$.

Hope this helps!

Comment: +1 Great lesson in how detailed "precise" notation can trip someone up.  A simple sentence like "the product is the collection of all finite sums of products $ab$ with $a\in I$, $b\in J$" would have assisted greatly in avoiding the wrong turn described here.

Comment: Thank you for the answer I understand the concept but I still don’t understand the notation

Comment: @MiguelSanchez, the notation is saying that $IJ$ is the set of things you can get by adding any (finite) number of terms that look like $a\cdot b$ where $a \in I$ and $b\in J$. Have you taken linear algebra? You can think of the elements of $IJ$ as a linear combination of the "simple products" $ab$.

Comment: I think i’m missing something $a_0 \in I$ refers to its first element or it is just some random element  and notation it's used to difference between elements where $ i\neq j \space then \space a_i \neq a_j$ ?

Comment: @MiguelSanchez, it's the latter. In general, elements of an ideal don't have a first elment. Take for example the ideal of even integers. What is its first element? Is it $2$? Is it $-2$? is it $-31415926$? Sets are generally not ordered. However, we can repeat elements in our sum representation if we want. Meaning that it's possible that we can have $i\neq j$ but still have $a_i = a_j$. This might be useful if you wanted to multiply the same "$a$" by a different "$b$", for example.

Comment: Thank you a lot, really helped me.

Comment: @MiguelSanchez My pleasure! Good luck with your studies!